# How to find n%(k*k) without integer overflow?

Tags: c++, modular-arithmetic

I know that `(a*b)%m` is equal to `((a%m)*(b%m))%m`?

But how to calculate `a%(m*m)`?

Comment: If `m * m` can overflow then your result can be bigger than the maximum representable value. How to you plan to deal with that? Also, do note that `(a % m) * (b % m)` can overflow too if `m * m` is too big.

Comment: You might ask on [the Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) for equivalents of that expression.

Comment: Have a look at [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) (and similar libraries).

Comment: If `k*k` *would* overflow, it would be greater than `n` and the modulo operation should do nothing. Detecting that and doing nothing isn't too hard

Comment: Please provide constraints on the size of `a` and `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to calculate `a%(m*m)` without causing integer overflow.

```c
long long int a, m, sqrt_a, ans;
sqrt_a = sqrt(a);
if (sqrt_a < m) {
    ans = a; // since "m > sqrt_a" then a%(m*m) will be "a"
}
else {
   ans = a % (m*m); // since "m <= sqrt_a" then m*m won't cause overflow
}
```